# Mat::convertTo used with inplace matrix cause buffer overflow

Tags: opencv, overflow

I have a problem in with a inplace Mat::convertTo cause buffer overflow if destination and source data type is different.

Please, anyone having this problem too? Can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of OpenCV are you using? This seems to be a problem fixed a long time ago, in revision 2307. Try to update your lib and see if it works.

Comment: I need to use a old version, because the project isnt mine and is old. Thank you. I will try to port.